# Change XML Start Bias Values for Dutch

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

I would like to modify the start bias values for the Dutch in Civilization 5 Gods and Kings however I cannot find the path to the XML file that determines the start bias.

Usually the XML file for each civ would be located at:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\sid meier's civilization   v\assets\DLC\DLC_02\Gameplay\XML\CIV5Civilization_ ...`

however I cannot seem to find the dutch XML file! I understand the risks inherent to modding so I will create a copy of any modded files in case my game becomes erratic.

I would like to change the start bias values so that I can spawn next to the ocean, and next to flood plains so that I can construct polders and a large navy. xD

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct path for G&K?  I think it's "Expansion" and not "DLC_02" - although they are not particularly consistent in their directory naming, and I'm away from steam at the moment to check.

Comment: I already checked that dir but I only find Polynesia, Denmark, Babylon and Mongolia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder should be:

`<steam installation folder>\steamapps\common\Sid Meier's Civilization V\Assets\DLC\Expansion\Gameplay\XML\Civilizations\`

And the particular file you're looking for is `CIV5Civilizations_Expansion.xml`. The dutch are actually already there:

```
<Civilization_Start_Region_Priority>
    <Row>
        <CivilizationType>CIVILIZATION_CELTS</CivilizationType>
        <RegionType>REGION_FOREST</RegionType>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <CivilizationType>CIVILIZATION_NETHERLANDS</CivilizationType>
        <RegionType>REGION_GRASS</RegionType>
    </Row>
</Civilization_Start_Region_Priority>
```

But remember that to enable them to start next to the ocean you want to add them under the `Civilization_Start_Along_Ocean` table, not under `Civilization_Start_Region_Priority`. I'm pretty sure you can't actually specify flood plains, though, only things such as grasslands / hills / mountains etc..

Comment: This sounds promising. So the Netherlands only gets bloody grass?! However, I am sure if you add a parameter for REGION_DESERT (is this correct?) and with the ocean start bias you will get flood plains. Seldom are civs placed in the desert without floodplains. 

Great answer! I will test it as soon as I have time.